# Will stateless widget be rebuilt again?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, statelesswidget

I am making a list of stateless widget as shown below and passing the id as the parameter to the widgets.

Code for cartPage:-

```
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  bool loading=true;
  List<CartTile> cartTiles=[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(currentUser!=null)
      getData();
  }

  getData()async
  {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot=await cartReference.doc(currentUser.id).collection('cartItems').limit(5).get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      cartTiles.add(CartTile(id: doc.data()['id'],index: cartTiles.length,));
    });
    setState(() {
      loading=false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: loading?Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator():SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: cartTiles,
                ),
              ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code for CartTile:-

```
    class CartTile extends StatelessWidget {
      final String id;
      CartTile({this.id,});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: productReference.doc(id).snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapshot)
          {
//here am using the snapshot to build the cartTile.
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

So, my question is whenever I will call setState in my homepage then will the stateless widget be rebuilt and increase my document reads. Because i read somewhere that when we pass the same arguments or parameters to a stateless widget then due to its cache mechanism it doesn't re build. If it will increase my reads then is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: without stateful widget you cannot use setState() method

Comment: in my homepage i am having statefull widget and after loading data am using setState() method

Comment: yes but where ypu are using setState() is that class statefull ??

Comment: see I have added my whole homepage or cartpage and in initState am calling the function to rebuild the state. You can see am using limit on documents and will be using the scroll controller to get more data and rebuild the state after that.

Comment: anyway thanks for your help i found a way am now generating the list of the stateless widget in getData only and using that list to show children of column. So even after setState it won't rebuild the stateless widget.

Comment: welcome... thats good